# Make Jest for LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, unit-test, code-coverage, lwc-jest, js

I have controller.js . It returns the ID of the case and displays duplicates of this case on the case page. The code works without problems, but it doesn't work with tests in any way

```
import { LightningElement, wire, track, api } from 'lwc';
import getCases from '@salesforce/apex/CaseController.getCases';

const COLUMNS = [
    { label: 'Case Number', fieldName: 'CaseNumber'},
    { label: 'Case Origin', fieldName: 'Origin' },
    { label: 'SuppliedEmail', fieldName: 'SuppliedEmail', type: 'email' },
    { label: 'Status', fieldName: 'Status' },
    { label: 'Reason', fieldName: 'Reason' },
    { label: 'Owner', fieldName: 'OwnerId' }
];

export default class CaseDuplicates extends LightningElement {
    @track columns = COLUMNS;
    @api recordId;
    @wire(getCases, {caseId:'$recordId'}) cases;
}
```

[image]

This is my first experience to write Jest

Comment: What have you written for a test so far? Where are you stuck? How can we help you?

Comment: I trying write this , I  added screenshot

Comment: Please make sure you edit your question if you need to add clarifications. Your answer will be deleted, since it is not an answer to the question. Also, I suggest you copy-paste your code as text so it is easier for people to copy-paste into their own IDE and test it.

Comment: If you're going to remove all the text to the question you may as well delete it. Otherwise, I'd recommend you'd [edit] and put the question back as it can help others.

Comment: Stop defacing your question. The contents of your question are important for understanding the answer that you've received. This site isn't here just to help you, it's also here to help other people who are looking for answers to similar problems that they themselves are facing.

Answer (score 1):

Your main problem is that you didn't wait for a render cycle, so you can't query the button you're trying to query.

```
it('Must accept recordId and return duplicate cases', async () => {
  // previous code is fine
  // ...
  document.body.appendChild(element);
  await Promise.resolve(); // Allow the DOM to render
  // ...
}
```

You also need to emit a wire event in order for the getCases method to receive data. This is a little more complicated, so I'll leave for you a link to the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.unit_testing_using_wire_utility).